# How to configure a microservices project in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am in a microservices project where we are creating around 120 microservices. How do I configure azure devops for this project? Do I have to create a new project for each microservice? I would like to keep the dash for project monitoring

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you [create an organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/sign-up-invite-teammates?view=vsts) and [a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/create-project?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fuser-guide%2Ftoc.json&%3Bbc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fuser-guide%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).
Then you can use create a git repository for each microservice, 120 microservices in 120 repos.

You can read about how Microsoft uses git [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/learn/devops-at-microsoft/use-git-microsoft).

TL;DR version quoted below.

**Mono Repo or Multi-Repo with Git**

> It's worth pausing to reflect that this isn't the only way. While
>   we've elected to have a single monolithic repository (the
>   "mono-repo"), other products at Microsoft use a multi-repo approach.
>   Skype, for instance, has hundreds of small repositories that get
>   stitched together in various combinations to create their many
>   different clients, services, and tools. Especially for teams embracing
>   microservices, multi-repo can be the right approach. TFS/Azure DevOps,
>   like many products at Microsoft, began as a monolith, and its code
>   organization reflects that